# Como cambiar el [src] de una imagen en Angular 7

Tags: angular, typescript, imagen

Tengo mi vista en Angular y quiero cambiar la imagen, utilicé databinding pero al darle `click` no me cambia de imagen, que estoy realizando mal ? Inclusive al pintar el valor de `superball` no me arroja nada en la consola web, gracias.

Deseo cambiarla por `'../../../assets/images/png/up-arrow.png'`

**.html**

```
<td style="padding-left: 50px;cursor: pointer;" mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
    <img (click)="functioninTypeScript($event.target)" style="width: 30px;height:30px" [src]="superball" />
 </td>
```

**.ts**

```
export class PokelistaComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

superball = '../../../assets/images/png/superball.png';

constructor() ...

functioninTypeScript(image: any) {
    this.superball = image.src;
    this.superball = (image.src === this.superball) ?
    this.superball = '../../../assets/images/png/up-arrow.png' : this.superball;
    console.log(this.superball);
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Implemente tu código en StackBlitz y funciono, intenta limpiando la cache de tu navegador, el siguiente es el link de la implementación.

[Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-a1yvw7)

Adicionalmente cambie un poco el HTML

```
<td style="padding-left: 50px;cursor: pointer;">
   <img (click)="functioninTypeScript($event.target)" style="width: 30px;height:30px" [src]="superball" />
</td>
```

Quite la parte

> *matCellDef="let element"

Answer (score 0):

Usa la ruta desde assets [src]="assets/imagen.png"
Esto debería funcionar ..............